# Using Scala worksheet with maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, maven

Just downloaded Scala IDE and imported a maven Java project that uses [Gatling](http://gatling.io/#/) loadtests. Im my maven file I have the following Scala plugin:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${scala-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
```

Now I was hoping this would be all I need to work with a split Java/Scala project and get all the power from the Scala IDE. However, the Scala worksheet does not display any output on save.

The project im working with is called `scala-and-java-test-project`

My question is what is required for me to be able to work with Scala worksheets in a Java maven project?

Comment: Have you configured it as a Scala project (you should see an 'S' on the folder)? Try right click on the project -> configure -> Add Scala Nature

Comment: I dont want to make the whole project into a scala project if that changes things in the project or is it only a IDE setting?

Comment: Only changes the Eclipse metadata (.project and .classpath files)